# Determine fragment to load based on value retrieved using Android DataStore

Tags: android

Usually in apps, there is a sort of a tutorial or onboarding screen that is opened only the first time the app launches and for subsequent launches it does not show. This is implemented by saving a value in the `SharedPreferences` and reading that value to determine whether or not to navigate to that screen.

The problem that I am facing is that I am using Android Navigation component and DataStore. DataStore provides the data as a flow (asynchronously). However, when my activity launches, I want it to set the starting fragment as either the OnboardingFragment or the HomeFragment. Since DataStore fetches data asynchronously, there might be a delay in fetching that value. Is there a way using DataStore that I can achieve this?

I tried out using DataStore and it does work but there is a delay before the fragment is displayed. This results in a bad UX where the user has to wait for a couple of seconds before the proper screen is displayed.

Comment: Maybe you need a https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: @KenWolf I do have a SplashScreen. However I am not loading any data in it as of yet. Do you suggest that I load the data their and pass it along?

Comment: Yes Splash screen is a good place to load data